# Putting Result sets into a temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, resultset

I have a procedure called Insert and the code looks like:

```
Create procedure Gen_insert
As
BEGIN


create table #temp
 ( insert_stmt varchar(max) ) 
 insert into #temp  
EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Admin'

 insert into #temp  
EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Impas'

 insert into #temp 
 EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Asui'

 insert into #temp 
 EXEC Generate_Insert @Table = 'Alstd'  

select * from #temp 

End
```

When I execute it I am getting following error:

```
Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Gen_Insert, Line 73
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: why on earth would you name your proc something like `INSERT`?

Comment: why on earth are you not doing the correct thing and writing the inserts rather than using a general insert proc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.` The error message is quite clear. You are nesting INSERT ... EXEC. statements. Either the procedures you call (`Generate_Insert`) use again INSERT ... EXEC or the caller of `insert` procedure uses it in an INSERT ... EXEC. Only you can find which is the case. As a rule of thumb, INSERT ... EXEC should be avoided, because of [this and other problems](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC).